# Scaling in Opera 12 Windows

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, opera

The pictures are not scaled correct after change zoom in Opera 12.17.
[image]

Comment: Zooming is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

We don't support zooming.

If you zoom in/out and get visual glitches, that's expected. We will not be fixing them.